# Атлас спрайтов: как загружать, маппить?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, render, спрайт

Комплексный вопрос. И так, есть png'шка на которой кучас тайлов 30x30. Я с помощью `Sprite Editor` все это порезал и получил атлас (я правильно называю сущьность?):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, мне хотелось бы каждый элемент атласа как-то замаппить на константы:

```
public class TitleMap
{
    public const string GROUND_DESERT = "desert";
    public const string GROUND_GREEN_GRASS = "green_grass";
    public const string GROUND_SANDY_LOAM = "sandy_loam";


    // Common roads
    public const byte NEW_VERT_ROAD = 1;
    public const byte NEW_HORZ_ROAD = 2;
    public const byte BRK_VERT_ROAD = 3;
    public const byte BRK_HORZ_ROAD = 4;
    public const byte RSD_HORZ_ROAD = 6;
    public const byte CROSS_ROAD    = 8;

    // Rotated roads
    public const byte RTT_BOTTOM_RIGHT_ROAD = 10;
    public const byte RTT_BOTTOM_LEFT_ROAD = 11;
    public const byte RTT_TOP_LEFT_ROAD = 12;
    public const byte RTT_TOP_RIGHT_ROAD = 13;

    // Decor
    public const byte GREENERY_BUSH = 15;
    public const byte GREENERY_TREE_1 = 16;
    public const byte GREENERY_TREE_2 = 17;
    public const byte GREENERY_TREE_3 = 18;

    // ......
}
```

Для того, что бы мне присылали `CSV` с этими значениями, уже после по ним я рендерил эти спрайты.

Итого: как загружать атлас, потом использовать, предварительно замаппив на константы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public const int CountAtlas= 10;
public Dictionary<int, Sprite[]> allSprites;

void Start () {
    allSprites = new Dictionary<int, Sprite[]>();
    for(int i= CountAtlas - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        allSprites.Add(i, Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Test" + i));
    }
}
//Функция для запроса спрайта
public Sprite GetSprite(int idAtlas,int idSprite)
{
    return allSprites[idAtlas][idSprite];
}
```

Можно так загружать из атласов спрайты( тут "Test"+i имя/путь атласа в папке Resources). И свести свои константы к индексам от 0-N для каждого атласа.
Можно делать это при старте игры, либо заранее в скрипт сложить.

p.s. В таком подходе с константами огромный МИНУС, если надо будет удалить какой-нибудь спрайт по середине или в начале атласа, все остальное надо будет перенумеровывать.

p.s.s.
Жесткой связки константы и номера в атласе можно избежать как то так:

```
    class SpriteInfo
{
    public Sprite sprite;
    public int index;
}
public const int CountAtlas = 10;
Dictionary<int, SpriteInfo[]> allSprites;
//зарезервированное имя для спрайтов в атласе
public const string NameSpriteInAtlas="sprite";

public void SetSprites()
{
    allSprites = new Dictionary<int, SpriteInfo[]>();
    int startIndex = NameSpriteInAtlas.Length;
    List<SpriteInfo> list = new List<SpriteInfo>();
    for (int i = CountAtlas - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Test" + i);
        for(int j= sprites.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            Sprite spr= sprites[j];
            int ind;
            if (CheckSprite(spr.name, startIndex,out ind))
            {
                list.Add(new SpriteInfo() { sprite = spr, index = ind });
            }
        }
        if (list.Count != 0) allSprites.Add(i, list.ToArray());
        list.Clear();
    }
}

public const int Title1 = 0;
public const int Title2 = 1;
public const int Title3 = 2;
public const int Title4 = 3;

bool CheckSprite(string nameSprite,int startIndex,out int index)
{
    index = -1;
    int num;
    if (!int.TryParse(nameSprite.Substring(startIndex), out num)) goto Label1;
    switch (num)
    {
        case Title1: index = Title1; return true;
        case Title2: index = Title2; return true;
        case Title3: index = Title3; return true;
        case Title4: index = Title4; return true;
    }
    Label1:
    Debug.LogError(GetType()+ " error: nameSprite="+ nameSprite+" is not exist");
    return false;
}
//Функция для запроса спрайта
public Sprite GetSprite(int idAtlas,int idSprite)
{
    if (!allSprites.ContainsKey(idAtlas))
    {
        Debug.LogError(GetType() + " error: idAtlas=" + idAtlas + " is not exist");
        return null;
    }
    SpriteInfo[] list = allSprites[idAtlas];
    for(int i= list.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (list[i].index == idSprite) return list[i].sprite;
    }
    Debug.LogError(GetType() + " error: idSprite=" + idSprite + " is not exist");
    return null;
}
```

Суть в том, что ты задаешь имена спрайтам в зависимости от этих констант, тогда можешь проверить, что в среди спрайтов есть имя с такой константой.

Остается только переименовать все спрайты как нужно и зашить им индекс в зависимости от константы. Можно это сделать индивидуально для каждого атласа(в моем случае для всех атласов). И при добавлении или удалении новой константы для спрайта, нужно еще и CheckSprite править, за то нумерация не поедет, и не нужно для каждого атласа делать нумерацию с 0-N.

Такая проверка небольшой Overhead при старте даст, поэтому это лучше заранее сделать и сохранить.

Comment: зачем в коде `goto Label1`,  если можно  строку `Debug.LogError(GetType()+ " error: nameSprite="+ nameSprite+" is not exist");
    return false;` перенести до `switch`? ...... `case` вообще упростить можно......... сдается мне тут какой-то костыль нарисован)

Comment: Та можно вообще сделать функцию положить туда Debug.LogError и вызывать функцию, это сделано для примера.
Case упростить до чего? там специально вставлены константы с которыми надо сравнивать, они могут разные цифры иметь.